# Node-RED Responsive Dashboards

Tags: css, frontend, dashboard, node-red

I'm creating a Node-RED dashboard. Until now, the dashboard looks like this:

[image]

However, when I change the width of the screen to small sizes, I get a dynamic response only from the top elements. Then, the page looks like this:

[image]

I tried (without success) to solve this problem implementing the following css code in a dashboard template node:

```
`<style>
@media (max-width: 1700px) {
        ui-card-panel #Monitoramento_FV_Você_já_economizou.visible {
            width: auto !important;
        }
    }
</style>`
```

ps: "ui-card-panel #Monitoramento_FV_Você_já_economizou.visible" refers to the page element that isn't responding to the screen width changes

[image]

I'd expected that this element adjust to the screen width just like the elements above

Comment: The problem is likely to be the jschart inside the component not resizing automatically

Comment: Have you tried `width: 100%` rather than `width: auto`?

Comment: @BrettDonald, yes. I've already tried this.